# Can someone explain the colors in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++, color-scheme

I started my graduate program and I have to work with a very complex code in C++ (a language that I don't know), I am taking some online courses online to learn the language, but I am also going through the code to see if I can make some sense of it.
The problem is that I don't know what the colors on the theme mean.

The code looks like this:

[image: The code]

I understand some of the colors:
Blue: variable types
Green: Comments
Orange: Printable text
white: functions, variables, etc.
The problem is with the colors Grey, Pink and Cyan. I don't know what they represent.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio, and the color theme is "Dark".
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as an image. This doesn't make sense!

Comment: In this specific case it looks like, grey is method parameters, pink is constants and cyan is keywords.   You can go to Options -> Environment -> Fonts and colors and see how visual studio is set to display for each type of display item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check its meaning by entering (in Microsoft Visual Studio) to:

> Tools > Options > Enviroment > Fonts and Colors

Check the "Display Items" and select the C++ items - you'll get its meaning "in color",

For example: C++ Macros are shown in a light purple.